# What is "int * a[][10];"?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The question is in the title:

What is `int * a[][10];`

Is it an array of pointers to arrays of int? I tried to youse the clockwise/spiral rule but I am not sure...

Comment: It's a two dimensional array of `int` pointers.

Comment: it's ... a bad idea :) specially with a C++ tag in the question.

Comment: [http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*+a%5B%5D%5B10%5D%3B](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*+a%5B%5D%5B10%5D%3B)

Comment: @tkausl Cool link. Though it translates C gibberish into English gibberish :)

Comment: That's a deliberately obtuse expression of something that shouldn't even be in C++ code in the first place. It's a pointer to a variable length array of *arrays of 10 integers*. Why you would want such a thing is a mystery to me.

Comment: @tkausl: beats `regex101.com` by a distance!

Comment: @tadman: It's not a pointer to a variable length array. It's an array (of incomplete type) of arrays of pointers to `int`. (Incomplete array types and variable length array types are two different things. VLAs exist only in C. They were added in C99 and made optional in C11.)

Comment: @tadman Why shouldn't it even be in C++ code? Because I should rather use vector for something like this for example?

Comment: @FelB: It's not clear what you should use instead, because it's not clear what you're trying to do. What actual problem are you trying to solve, and why do you think `int * a[][10];` might be a solution?

Comment: @Nothing actual. I am just learning C++, trying to get used to it and practice reading declarations

Comment: @FelB Exactly. `std::vector` or one of its friends is the best way to store variable length arrays. You may want to use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to create a two dimensional structure. Normally I'd make a singular array that's simply 10x longer and write an interface that handles the mapping for you.

Comment: @tadman Making it 1D is also much better from the point of view of cache-locality: all data is guaranteed to be stored contiguously, so accessing "close" elements should be fast. A `vector<vector>` doesn't have this guarantee: the individual pointers of the outer vector are not necessarily pointing to consecutive memory areas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int * a[][10];
```

is an illegal declaration in C++, as the storage size isn't known. You need to initialize it with arrays of 10 pointers to `int`, like so:

```
int* a[][10] = {{nullptr}}; // initialize with one array, the latter consisting of null pointers
```

or, even simpler,

```
int* a[][10] = {{}};
```

Once initialized, it becomes an array of arrays-10 of pointers to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`int *a[][10]`, is to be read as pointer to 2D array of undefined rows (by default I guess it is 0) and 10 columns,with data read out row-wise in memory layout.
But this declaration is only possible in C.

If we declare a 2D array namely int abc[10][10] then we can make 'a' to point this array 'abc'.

Comment: Incorrect. `a` not a pointer to a 2D array, it's a 2D array of pointers. Try the `cdecl` command if you have it, or http://cdecl.org/

Comment: Thanks,i wrote it wrong.

Comment: It's still wrong; `a` is not a pointer.